# classes and methods in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

*in Dart:*

1. if we want to use **a method**, we say `objectName.methodName()`.
2. if we want to use a **static(class) method**, we say `className.methodName()`; like `int.parse()` or `double.parse()`.

*Question:*
`readLineSync()` is **a method (not a class method )** of **Stdin class** of dart:io library (According to Dart API Docs). But why when we use this method we say:
`stdin.readLineSync()` ?!

Thanks

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/stdin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if you check in the source code `stdin` is a getter on an instance of an `Stdin` object which means that calling `stdin.readLineSync()` is like calling an object `Stdin().readLineSync()`.

Inside the file `stdio.dart` you can find the following implementation for `stdin`:

```dart
/// The standard input stream of data read by this program.
Stdin get stdin {
  return _stdin ??= _StdIOUtils._getStdioInputStream(_stdinFD);
}
```

Which is a global method to get a single instance of `stdin`.